# Vue - Checking data has been set before running function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am having an issue with the time taken for `data` to update, when a function is called.

In the example below, when an option is selected, the plugin sets the element 'inputs.example' (I can see this on in the Vue Tools) to the option picked, when the option is picked it triggers a function (`triggerFunction()`), however it appears that the function is getting triggered before the application has time to set the data. As a result im getting 'null' data, even though it appears to be available.

How do I ensure the data is set before the function is run?

Thanks.

Dropdown

```
<Multiselect
 v-model="inputs.example"
 :options="options"
 @select="triggerFunction(options.vendorOptions)">
 </Multiselect>
```

Function

```
triggerFunction() {
      if (this.inputs.example != null) {
        fetch(`${API_URL}api/v1/endpoint/${this.inputs.example._id}`, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
              authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.token}`
            }
          })
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(output. => {
            console.log(output);
          });
      } else {
        console.log("No Option Selected";
      }
    }
```

Comment: `Who` is Multiselect component and how it works?
I guess you should use @select="triggerFunction" and receive selected values in function itself:
`function triggerFunction (selectedItems) { ... }`. Or similar

Comment: Multiselect is a library. I was looking for a solution, that preferably doesn't involve amending the library's code :)